# JTable Actionlistener on click an row with parameter

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a table created over AbstractTableModel. In this table I have a rows. And I need add ActionListener with parameter from column "ID from database" - viz. Image. This ActionListener should call when you double click the row. 
[Image](http://s27.postimg.org/vhbory7g3/jtable_Abstract.png)

So my question is how to get the parameter from the table ActionListener to JDialog.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a `MouseListener` to detect when the user clicks the table, [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details
- Use [`JTable#columnAtPoint(Point)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint(java.awt.Point)) and [`JTable#rowAtPoint(Point)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint(java.awt.Point)) to get the row and column values for the point the user clicked at
- Use [`JTable#getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) to get the value of the cell at the given row/column position

Comment: Use a MouseListener to detect when the user clicks the table == ListSelectionListener, MouseListener pretty ignored KeyEvents

Comment: @mKorbel But, `ListSelectionListener` doesn't detect *"when you double click the row"* so it won't meet the requirements